# Angular 2 how to remove pasted content from input

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do some stuff with a pasted string, which works, but when I try to remove the content I can't seem to do it since the pasted content isn't getting bound to the model of the input.

How can you clear the input of the pasted content?

I tried binding the content to the model and then removing the model but that will still leave the actual pasted content in the event object so it's not a solution.

Also tried clearing the input directly using `input.value = ''` but without luck.

Markup:

```html
<input #input [(ngModel)]="newTag[labelKey]" (paste)="onPaste($event)">
```

Function:

```js
onPaste(e: any) {

  let content = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

  // Do stuff 

  // Then clear pasted content from the input
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clear the variable you bound the model to:

```js
onPaste(e: any) {

  let content = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

  // Do stuff 

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.newTag = "";
  }, 0);
}
```

For some reason the text stays in the input, when calling `this.newTag = ""` synchronously and if you set it to `this.newTag = "foo"` the text in the input is `fooPASTEDTEXT`.

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7WURQUAgZgfqx0Ia8l7O?p=preview) for working example

Comment: Maybe you need to call a change detection or something? Although I already emit the overall model value after doing it.